# How to convert CArchive to CStdioFile?

Tags: c++, mfc

I've recently dug up this old project that basically read and writes into a file using MFC's `CArchive` and come across this code:

```
void CTableBuilderAppDoc::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    if (ar.IsStoring())
    {
        m_pTableBuilder->Serialize(ar);
    }
    else
    {
        if (m_pTableBuilder != NULL)
        {
            delete m_pTableBuilder;
        }

        TableBuilder *table = new TableBuilder();
        table->Serialize(ar);
        m_pTableBuilder = table;
        
        this->UpdateAllViews(NULL, LOADED_DATA, NULL);
    }
}
```

This gives an error for the `Serialize` calls:

> a reference of type "CStdioFile &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "CArchive"

I'm basically new to MFC and Googling this problem shows me no clear results.

Is there a way to convert `CArchive` to `CStdioFile`?

Changing the receiving type to `CArchive` is not possible, as this method is also called by other code, which passes the `CStdioFile` type.

Comment: Please show code, not images of code. It doesn't help that you're making sure that we cannot see vital details. Show a [mcve].

Comment: The reason i attached the actual image is so that we can view clearly the error and where it is happening.
I've already converted the image into the code and hope i did give it a clear context

Comment: Create a `CStdiofile`, pass it to Serialize, then extract data from it and write it to `CArchive`. Maybe worth switching from `CStdiofile` to `CFile` to be able to use `CMemFile`

Comment: The `CArchive` class has a `GetFile()` member, which returns a pointer to its underlying file object. But that's a `CFile*` (likely in binary mode), not a `CStdioFile*` (which typically works in text mode).

Comment: Please show the compiler diagnostic, unabridged, and the specific line it is issued for. Also, the code provided is far from complete. We don't know what `m_pTableBuilder` is, for example.

Comment: Answering the literal question: You can't. With that out of the way, what's the specific *problem* you are trying to solve? Why are you providing a serialization implementation based on `CArchive` when you immediately go ahead and try to avoid using it?

Comment: You have a few Serialize functions in your code. Please indicate the actual signatures of these functions.